# How wormhole in this paper behave?

Tags: astrophysics, wormholes

I discovered [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.08975v1) paper that describes a wormhole without the use of exotic mass, and wondered at what's this wormhole's behavior. The problem is I don't know what most of equation on this paper is doing, and can't really tell the behavior of this wormhole.

Even more, I discovered that the paper predicted that its throat radius is equal to square root of 10/11 multiplied by two times its mass, but I can't tell what units they're using. If that's SI Units, then a 1 kg wormhole described in this paper would have 1.9 meter radius. **Is it true?** ***[Note: Per Ben Crowel's comment on the use of geometrised units, I've solved it. I'll leave it here for historical reasons]***

Also in this paper it discusses gravitational radius, and r_sigma, I have no idea what all of this means. **What are the meanings of them?**

I'm a layman and only have high school physics understanding, so it would be very helpful if anyone here could understand this paper. So it comes to my last question, **what's the behavior of this wormhole? Is it traversable and stable?**

**NB:** I'm not sure where to put this question, on worldbuilding or physics, but given the question's strong leaning to contemporary physics and have nothing to do with worldbuilding, (despite its intended usage in worldbuilding's) I decided to ask it here.

*(Also, If you're going to downvote this question, please do put a comment on what this question is lacking, it would be very appreciated)*

Comment: Relativists normally use geometrized units: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system

Comment: @BenCrowell thank you for pointing that. It explained a third of the entire question, I suspected that because on some papers they use the assumption that G=c=1, but I have no idea about the name of such system, until you mentioned it.